# What is the event that fires when flowplayer finished downloading the clip?

Tags: javascript, events, flowplayer

I am having problems determining when  a clip has fully downloaded in Flowplayer. In the project i am working it is important there are no buffering pauses during the playback so i must be shure that the clip is fully loaded/downloaded.

The onLoad event fires when the player is loaded (not the clip) so not good.

Any idea if there is such event or how my application can know when the clip has fully downloaded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's only `onBufferFull` when the clip buffer is filled completely.

You might want to try adding a second clip to your playlist after the main video and then add a `onNetStreamEvent` or `onMetaData` to that clip so you will know when the second clip received network data and therefore begins loading.

http://flowplayer.org/documentation/events/clip.html

To make sure there are no buffering pauses you might also consider to use a higher Buffer value, let's say something aroung the entire clip length?! There's a property called `bufferLength` for that:

http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/clips.html